# Gzip output different after Python restart

Tags: python, gzip, deterministic

I'm trying to gzip a numpy array in Python 3.6.8.

If I run this snippet twice (different interpreter sessions), I get different output:

```
import gzip
import numpy
import base64

data = numpy.array([[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0], [13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0]])
compressed = base64.standard_b64encode(gzip.compress(data.data, compresslevel=9))
print(compressed.decode('ascii'))
```

Example results (it's different every time):

```
H4sIAPjHiV4C/2NgAIEP9gwQ4AChOKC0AJQWgdISUFoGSitAaSUorQKl1aC0BpTWgtI6UFoPShs4AABmfqWAgAAAAA==
H4sIAPrHiV4C/2NgAIEP9gwQ4AChOKC0AJQWgdISUFoGSitAaSUorQKl1aC0BpTWgtI6UFoPShs4AABmfqWAgAAAAA==
      ^
```

Running it in a loop (so the same interpreter session),it gives the same result each time

```
for _ in range(1000):
    assert compressed == base64.standard_b64encode(gzip.compress(data.data, compresslevel=9))
```

How can I get the same result each time? (Preferably without external libraries.)

Comment: Why does that matter to you?

Comment: What happens when you add a mtime=0 parameter to gzip.compress(data.data, compresslevel=9)?

Comment: @SinanKurmus Doesn't exist, but if I create my own BytesIO and GzipFile with mtime then it indeed works! Do you want to turn it into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gzip uses some file information (inodes, timestamp, etc) when compressing (good discussion of that [here](https://medium.com/@mpreziuso/is-gzip-deterministic-26c81bfd0a49)). You are not using files per se but still you are doing it at different times. So that may have an effect (a look at Python's gzip wrapper would actually give a better insight but that is beyond me:)

So try using the `mtime=0` parameter in `gzip.compress(data.data, compresslevel=9)` if you have Python 3.8+, as

```
gzip.compress(data.data, compresslevel=9, mtime=0)
```

and if that does not work (e.g. older Python version), then you can use `gzip.GzipFile` with the `mtime` parameter, like this:

```
buf = io.BytesIO()
with GzipFile(fileobj=buf, mode='wb', compresslevel=compresslevel, mtime=0) as f:
    f.write(data)
result = buf.getvalue()
```

For details, the documentation is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html):